# glsl effect on low poly surface

Tags: glsl

I've got a vertex/fragment shader, point light and attenuation, I need to apply such shader to a cube face and I need to see a change in gradation of colours, if I use an high poly mesh
everything works quite well and the effect it's nice my goal is to have a gradient on this low poly mesh.

I tried to do this gl_FragColor = vec4(n,1) n = normal but I get a solid colour per surface
and this can be the reason why I don't see a gradation?

cheers

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the problem with low poly mesh? How are effects different? *What have you tried?* Please, read SO tutorial and try to improve your question, as it's unlikely to get answered in current form.

Comment: Hi Bartek, can you tell me where is the faq? i am not terrible experienced using so I ma sorry :) I tried to write some shader for illumination, phong, blinn, adding attenuation but I get solid colors on my cube face while I need to get a gradation.I can't easily debug a glsl shader and this does not help.

Comment: There's a link at the top of the page. Also you should edit your answer and put your additional information there.

Comment: Most likely, your normals are bad. 95% sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct behaviour that you are observing. Cube is perfectly flat, thus it's normals per face vertex are the same.

Note however, that in calculations of Phong lighting you also should use the position of fragment, which is interpolated between 3 (or 4, when using quads) vertices of the given (sub)face. It can be used to calculate angle between light position and eye vector in the given fragment's position.

I've experienced similar problems lately, and I figured out that your cube really needs to shine, if you want to see something non-flat; and I mean literally. Set the shininess to reasonably high value (250-500). You should see a focused, moving point of light on the face that is reflecting directly to you. If not, your lightning shader is probably wrong.